# How do I make Firefox auto-refresh on file change?

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

Does anyone know of an extension for Firefox, or a script or some other mechanism, that can monitor one or more local files. Firefox would auto-refresh or otherwise update its canvas when it detected a change (of timestamp) in the files(s).

For editing CSS, it would be ideal if just the CSS could be reloaded, rather than a full HTML re-render.

Effectively it would enable similar behaviour to Firebug with its dynamic HTML/CSS editing, only through external files.

Comment: See [javascript - How do I make a local HTML page auto-refresh on file change? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858760/how-do-i-make-a-local-html-page-auto-refresh-on-file-change) for **`file://` protocol**. (not that there are very good solutions there.)

Comment: There's [an alternative solution that continuously `fetch()` the page to check for difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68089192/5267751) which I think works directly on Firefox. || See also question for Chrome: [vim - Auto-reload browser when I save changes to html file, in Chrome? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588658/auto-reload-browser-when-i-save-changes-to-html-file-in-chrome?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**[Live.js](http://livejs.com/)**

From the website:

> How?
>   Just include Live.js and it will monitor the current page including local CSS and Javascript by sending consecutive HEAD requests to the server. Changes to CSS will be applied dynamically and HTML or Javascript changes will reload the page. Try it!
>
> Where?
>   Live.js works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE6+ until proven otherwise. Live.js is independent of the development framework or language you use, whether it be Ruby, Handcraft, Python, Django, NET, Java, Php, Drupal, Joomla or what-have-you.

It has the huge benefit of working with [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), dynamically refreshing each open IE tab.

Try it out by adding the following to your `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://livejs.com/live.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is what I have been searching for a pretty long time and it works wonders!!! It detects the change and save of a page & instantly reloads the page and this saves me tons of time from having to reload the page every time I make a change! Thanks a ton for sharing!

Comment: Wow, thanks! Also for all, who will use it please note, that ```Live.js doesn't support the file protocol. It needs http.```

Comment: Didn't work me so I wrote php script and js script. JS scripts makes request every Nth second to php script and php script checks whether files got changed. If they did it let know js that page shoud be refreshed. You can specify what extensions and what directories you would like to watch. You only need to put two files into your project and you are done. No dependencies and no third-party software in your system. More details: http://alexshulzhenko.ru/web-development-autorefresh-page-on-changes

Comment: @antongorodezkiy That's true, but there is a simple work around by loading the HTML from within `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

Comment: @tebe the link is dead to your autorefresh-page

Comment: @Timo Here's an archived copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20190611080207/https://alexshulzhenko.ru/web-development-autorefresh-page-on-changes/

Comment: The github repo seems to be unmaintained and the bookmarklet in Firefox doesn't work any more (all is served from cache). I fixed this in my PR: https://github.com/Q42/LiveJS/pull/4

Answer (score 15):

Have a look at FileWatcher extension:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/filewatcher/

- it's a WebExtension, so it works with the latest Firefox
- it has a native app (to be installed locally) that monitors watched files for changes using native OS calls (no polling!) and notifies the WebExtension to let it reload the web page
- reload is driven by **rules**: a rule contains the page URL (with regular expression support) and its included/excluded **local** source files
- open source: https://github.com/coolsoft-ita/filewatcher

DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of the extension ;)

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend **[livejs](http://livejs.com/)**

But it has following **Advantages** and **Disadvantages**

**Advantages:**
1. Easy setup
2. Works seamlessly on different browsers (Live.js works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE6+)
3. Don't add irritating interval for refreshing browser specially when you want to debug along with designing
4. Only refreshing when you save change `ctrl + S`
5. Directly saves CSS etc from firebug I have not used that feature but read on their site http://livejs.com/ that they support it too!!!

**Disadvantages:**

1. It will not work on file protocol `file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/livejs/live.html`
2. You need to have server to run it like `http://localhost`
3. You have to remove it while deploying on staging/production
4. Doesn't serves **CDN** I have tried cheating & applying direct link http://livejs.com/live.js but it will not work you have to download and keep on local to work.

Comment: Disadvantages #1 and #2 are OK for me. #3 can easily be worked around with a conditional inclusion serverside (include only if domain=localhost for instance). But worse than these all: I can't get it working on my local EasyPhp dev install: neither ETag  nor Last-Modified headers seem to change on file updates :-(

Answer (score 6):

[Xrefresh](http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/) with firebug.

Comment: Is there a linux alternative by chance?

Comment: It has been superseded by [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/), which is shareware for Mac: $10. Don't know if it is free for other platforms. I'm using the free [Auto Reload](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-reload/) which is suggested by another comment.

Answer (score 6):

Firefox has an extension called mozRepl.

Emacs can plug into this, with moz-reload-on-save-mode.

when it's set up, saving the file forces a refresh of the browser window.

Comment: And for Vim it's mentioned at: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_refresh_display_of_html_on_saving_file

Answer (score 4):

You could just place a javascript interval on your page, have it query a  local script which checks the last date modified of the css file, and refreshes it if it changed.

jQuery Example:

```
var modTime = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  $.post("isModified.php", {"file":"main.css", "time":modTime}, function(rst) {
    if (rst.time != modTime) {
      modTime = rst.time;
      // reload style tag
      $("head link[rel='stylesheet']:eq(0)").remove();
      $("head").prepend($(document.createElement("link")).attr({
          "rel":"stylesheet",
          "href":"http://sstatic.net/mso/all.css?v=4372"
        })
      );
    }
  });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Yes, It sure could. Although it would require jQuery to be loaded on the page.

Comment: @CharlesRoper This is the bookmarklet you were looking for: http://www.pagereboot.com/

Answer (score 4):

There are some IDE's that contain this ability (They'll have a pane within them or some other means to auto-refresh a page on save).

If you want to do this yourself a quick hack is to set the [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/META_refresh) on the page to a low value - one or two seconds.

```
# Will refresh the page content every second
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this will cause the page to jump around if it has scrollbars.

Answer (score 4):

[Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/) can do this from the server side / outside of the browser.

This can achieve more repeatable results / things that don't require so much clicking.

This will serve a page and refresh on change

```
cd static_content
browser-sync start --server --files .
```

It also allows a scripting mode.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly *hacky*, but if you want to work locally without making any external request (to `live.js`, for example), or run any local server, I think this might be useful. This is not specific to web development, you can adopt similar strategy to any other workflow.

You will need two tiny tools (which are present in almost all distribution repos): `inotify-tools` and `xdotool`.

First get the `ID` of your Firefox and your editor window using `xdotool`.

```
$ xdotool search --name "Mozilla Firefox"
60817411
60817836
$ xdotool search --name "Pluma"  # Pluma is my editor
94371842
```

Depending on the number of processes running, you will get one or more window `ID`. Use `xdotool windowactivate <ID>` to know which one you want (the focus changes to the respective window).

Use `inotifywait -e close_write` to monitor changes to your local file and when you save the file using your editor, change focus to your browser, reload `xdotool key CTRL+R` and focus back to your editor. *This is so instantaneous you will not notice nothing.*

Also, `inotifywait` exits on change, so you might have to do it in a loop. Here is a minimum working example (in Bash in your working directory).

```
while /usr/bin/true
do
    inotifywait -e close_write index.html;
    xdotool windowactivate 60917411;  # Switch to Firefox
    xdotool key CTRL+R;               # Reload Firefox
    xdotool windowactivate 94371842   # Switch back to Pluma
done
```

- You can use `inotifywait` to watch for the entire directory or some selected files in your directory.
- You can write a script that can automate is easily.
- This works on Linux (I've tested this on Void Linux.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [live.js](https://livejs.com) with a [tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) script to avoid having to include `https://livejs.com/live.js` in your HTML file.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Auto reload
// @author       weirane
// @version      0.1
// @match        http://127.0.0.1/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    if (Number(window.location.port) === 8000) {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://livejs.com/live.js';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
})();
```

With this tampermonkey script, the live.js script will be automatically inserted to pages whose address matches `http://127.0.0.1:8000/*`. You can change the port according to your need.

Comment: This looks like the most straightforward answer. However, adding this to my flask app results in multiple calls being sent to the backend which errors out saying function did not return a valid response. I would assume the script wants something passed to the backend to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can solve it by using some ajax requests after a determinate interval. You can do a request to CSS files and then if you don't get the "not modified" header you delete your css and load it again. For dynamic files you do a request and store the response and then every time you make a request to that file you compare the response to the latest.