# JavaScript: run setInterval at page load

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to run a bit of code every 20 seconds. That works fine. But I'd like `setInterval` to be run when first encountered, and then to start timing (instead of doing the timing first).

Obviously, I can do something like:

```
myFunction();
setInterval(myFunction, 20000);
```

But I find that a little inelegant. I'd prefer to do something like

```
setInterval(myFunction, 20000, { waitBeforeFirstRun: false });
```

Does such a setting exist for `setInterval`?

Comment: Your example is flawed, you are calling the function instead of assigning it.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685396/execute-the-first-time-the-setinterval-without-delay .. I've also flaged it

Comment: I would go with first calling the function and then scheduling it for the sake of simplicity and maintainability.

Comment: @MateiMihai This is definitely a dup. What's it mean that you flagged it? Can I shut this whole thing down and just refer everyone to the other, older question?

Comment: @AlexStack It's a good approach. My actual code was a teeny bit more complex, so it seemed easier if I wouldn't have to do that. But it was my approach until I heard back from the community on if there is a better way. It doesn't really seem like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
setInterval(​function foo(){
    // logic
    return foo;
}(), 20000);​
```

Comment: Very elegant! For those readers with weak JavaScript skills (me, included), a tad bit of explanation of why both the `()` and the `return` statement are necessary would be very appreciated. This is JS-nerdy enough that I'm not sure putting it in my mostly-Rubyist-written codebase would be a good idea, and will likely still keep the `myFunction();setInterval(myFunction,20000);` implementation in place (since it's already written). But your solution satisfies my curiosity and teaches me interesting things about JS. An academic success! Thanks.

Comment: `()` will execute the function right away, and returning itself will inject the function reference into the setInterval.

Answer (score 5):

```
(function wrap(){
    myFunction();
    setTimeout( wrap, 20000 );
})();
```

Comment: Nice idea, but how is this more elegant than `myFunction();setInterval(myFunction, 20000);`? It seems to just add another named wrapper.

Comment: It's named but scoped to its body (named function expression), I.E. it won't do anything to the containing scope (global or otherwise)

Comment: It's a neat trick. As @David indicates, it's really just a matter of personal preference and the particulars of the situation which solution to use. I wouldn't necessarily replace my original approach with this (since my code is already written at this point, I find this solution not nearly compelling enough to go change it).