# Refresh a div with php data every 10 seconds using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, refresh

Am trying to refresh data stored in a div every 10 seconds using jQuery.

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#latestData").load("getLatestData.php #latestData");
        }, 10000);
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "latestData">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the PHP code I am using (temporarily as I know this won't change due to the same "data"):

```
<?php

    echo "test";

?>
```

However, it isn't even showing "test" on the html page.. could anyone suggest where I have gone wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery `load` method works in a different way. Try reading its [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

You don't have to specify destination element ID twice, remove the second one, like this:

```
$("#latestData").load("getLatestData.php");
```

Comment: Ah yes perfect, knew it would be something simple! Many thanks! One other small question, the text only appears after 10 seconds have passed, is there a way for it to appear straight away and then refresh after 10 seconds too?

Comment: @New_programmer There are a lot of ways to do this, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685396/execute-the-first-time-the-setinterval-without-delay

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way that will solve what you want to achieve, using the `$.get` method in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("getLatestData.php", function (result) {
            $('#latestData').html(result);
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh message count just use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#ID").load();
    }, 1000);
});
```