# Call function once, then setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a function that that I would like to call immediately, then use setInterval to update every ten seconds.

Currently I am using something like

```
myFunction();
setInterval(function(){
 myFunction();
}, 10000);
```

Is there a better way to do this?  I feel like there should be a way to tell setInterval to fire on call, but I cannot seem to find anything on it.

Comment: If that function has no params, you can pass it in with `setInterval(myFunc, 100000);` other than that, looks fine.

Comment: I've been using this language since 2007, and I think that's the only way to do it. That's just how `setInterval` works, really.

Comment: Wait, I just thought of something. I'll post an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute the setInterval function without delay the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685396/execute-the-setinterval-function-without-delay-the-first-time)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't any "better," but it does what you want with fewer lines:

```
myFunction();
setInterval(myFunction, 10000);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you return the function from inside the function, you can use a little hack like this:

```
function foo() {
    alert('hi');
    return foo;
}

// no need to call it before setting the interval
window.setInterval( foo() , 3000 );
```

---

It executes immediately, and since the function returns itself, it keeps going.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/thetenfold/wRSsc/)

Comment: Pretty cool idea. Let's hope there's no exceptions before the `return`, otherwise it won't act like the OP's original code

Comment: This hurts my eyes. It's almost as bad as `setInterval((foo(), foo), 3000)` which [works too](http://jsfiddle.net/47Df8/), but is so hard to read…

Comment: I agree. It's basically the only way to do what he asked for, though.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to modify your function to call itself with setTimeout, then you can start the whole thing with a single line:

```
function myFunction() {
    // do stuff
    setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);
}
myFunction();
```

As pointed out in the comments, this is not exactly the same as using `setInterval` (which may drop some function calls depending on how long the code in the function takes to execute).

Comment: Although this doesn't do *exactly* the same thing as `setInterval` (especially depending on what `// do stuff` actually is)

Comment: Nope. It's quite different from `setInterval`, especially between browsers.

Comment: Added a note about that.