# Why does setTimeout require anonymous function to work?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I was reading an answer on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6685414/634324) that explained how to use setTimeout to create a sort of recurring loop on a webpage. However, I am wondering why setTimeout requires an anonymous function to work. Consider the following code:

```
trainingTimer(60,0);

function trainingTimer(duration,c) {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Time left: "+(duration-c);
    if(duration==c) {
        alert("Time is up!");
    }
    else {
        window.setTimeout(trainingTimer(duration,c+1),1000);
    }
}
```

I wrote this based off the answer that I linked above, however when it runs it loops through all 60 `trainingTimer` calls at once, and immediately displays "Time left: 0" on my web page. However, if I modify

`window.setTimeout(trainingTimer(duration,c+1),1000);`

and wrap `trainingTimer(duration,c+1)` in an anonymous function like so

`window.setTimeout(function() {trainingTimer(duration,c+1)},1000);`

then the code works perfectly fine.

I am wondering why I have to wrap a named function inside an anonymous function in order for setInterval to work properly. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: `trainingTimer(someargs)` doesn't return a function, and setTimeout needs a function to execute.

Comment: @KevinB Technically it does not need a function...

Comment: i guess, kinda like `window.alert()` doesn't need an argument.

Comment: More on the lines that it can take a string and evaluate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
window.setTimeout(trainingTimer(duration,c+1),1000);
```

is the same as

```
var result = trainingTimer(duration,c+1);
window.setTimeout(result,1000);
```

It takes the result of the executed method and assigns it.

And since training timer method returns nothing. Your code is basically this

```
trainingTimer(duration,c+1);
window.setTimeout(undefined, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

The runtime has to evaluate the argument list passed to any function *before* it calls the function. The first thing you're passing to `setTimeout` in this code:

```
window.setTimeout( trainingTimer(duration,c+1), 1000 );
```

is *the result of calling a function*, not the function itself. Wrapping that in a function solves that problem.

The function doesn't have to be anonymous:

```
function callTrainingTimer() {
    trainingTimer( duration, c + 1);
}

// ...

window.setTimeout(callTrainingTimer, 1000);
```

works too.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's how `setTimeout` works.  It's first parameter is a function that you want it to run after x milliseconds.

When you do:

```
window.setTimeout(trainingTimer(duration,c+1),1000);
```

What you are doing is *running* `trainingTimer` immediately, and sending its return value to `setTimeout`.

You need to give it a function, that's why you do:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    trainingTimer(duration, c+1);
},1000);
```

There *is* a way to do it without a function, but it's ***NOT* recommended**.

```
window.setTimeout('trainingTimer(duration,c+1)', 1000);
```

This will use `eval()` to run the code.  This works instead of passing a function, but it is *not* recommended.  `eval()` is unsafe, do not use it.