# Why do I have to wrap functions in setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why do I have to write

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#selector').focus() }, 100);
```

instead of

```
setTimeout($('#selector').focus, 100);
```

The latter gives me a TypeError `this.trigger is not a function` in Firefox, but clearly it is a function since `typeof $('#selector').focus` is "function."  What's going on here?

Comment: might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640755/why-does-settimeout-require-anonymous-function-to-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the `this` problem. Per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem):

> Code executed by `setTimeout()` is called from a separate execution context to the function from which `setTimeout` was called. The usual rules for setting the `this` keyword for the called function apply, and if you have not set `this` in the call or with `bind`, it will default to the global (or `window`) object in non–strict mode, or be `undefined` in strict mode. It will not be the same as the this value for the function that called `setTimeout`.

In JavaScript, there's a concept of "execution contexts", which are contexts that hold information about what is currently executing. There's a global execution context, and when a function is called, a new execution context is created. The `this` value then depends on the execution context and is set according to the current execution context. Since `setTimeout` creates a new execution context when the target function is called, `this` does not represent the jQuery object from the DOM, but the global object (as it is by default, or undefined in strict mode). Thus when jQuery internally calls `this.trigger` it is trying to call `window.trigger` which does not exist.

Try using `Function#bind` which explicitly sets the `this` value:

```
setTimeout($('#selector').focus.bind($('#selector')), 100);
```

Or, as Ryan mentions:

```
setTimeout($.fn.focus.bind($('#selector')), 100);
```

Of course, you could, as squint mentioned, use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions) instead, which is faster than using `bind` and more idiomatic:

```
setTimeout(() => $('#selector').focus(), 100);
```