# Quirk while calling a method inside another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

There is an error in the last line of the code stating :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeClass' of undefined

why it is that there is no error in last-2nd and last-3rd line, but in the last-line? 
What's going on here?

```
var scrolling = {
    a : 9,
    b: 1,
    z: [0,1],
    $headerComponent : $(".header-wrapper"),

    funcInEvent1: function() {
        this.$headerComponent.removeClass("duringScroll-header");
    },
    rough: function(){
        var a = this.z; 
        console.log(a);
    }
};

$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    console.log(scrolling.$headerComponent); // <----- NO ERROR (object)
    scrolling.rough(); //<----- NO ERROR ( [0,1] );
    window.setTimeout(scrolling.funcInEvent1, 300); //<------ ERROR
}
```

The quirk will be fixed if i replace `this` with `scrolling` in the 8th line.

```
    funcInEvent1: function() {
        scrolling.$headerComponent.removeClass("duringScroll-header");
    },
```

Comment: The problem is not with the last line, it's that either `this.$headerComponent` or `scrolling.$navButton` is `undefined`

Comment: i edited and omitted the line of "scrolling.$navButton" because the issue is with this.$headerCompnent...

Comment: `this` inside an anonymous function is not what expect. keep using a separate variable or arrow functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the call to `scrolling.funcInEvent1` in an anonymous function :

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    console.log(scrolling.$headerComponent);
    scrolling.rough();
    window.setTimeout( function() {
        scrolling.funcInEvent1();
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: Ok But even if i do that, what's the logic behind that?? I am concerned completely with what's actually happening, what my piece of code is not working, and why wrapping the call (like u said) will work?

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945702/why-do-i-have-to-wrap-functions-in-settimeout