# javascript ajax setinterval delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, delay

How can I execute this function immediately, then start the setInterval timer?

Here is my js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var callAjax = function(){
          $.ajax({
            method:'get',
            url:'apinvs.php',
            dataType:'html',        
            success:function(data){
              $("#main").html(data); } 
          });
        }
                setInterval(callAjax,2500); 
      });
```

It's executing the function after 2.5 seconds.  It leaves the div blank until 2.5 seconds pass, which is what I don't want to happen. :(

I found a Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685396/execute-the-first-time-the-setinterval-without-delay) but I'm not sure how to apply it with my code (it's using document ready).  Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
setInterval(callAjax,2500);
```

to

```
callAjax();
setInterval(callAjax,2500);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just posted an answer (I figured it out myself, can't believe it was so simple).  Spot on!

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?
or do I get your question wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var callAjax = function(){
      $.ajax({
        method:'get',
        url:'apinvs.php',
        dataType:'html',        
        success:function(data){
          $("#main").html(data);
          setInterval(callAjax,2500); 
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, can't believe it was this simple.

Changed my code to..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var callAjax = function(){
          $.ajax({
            method:'get',
            url:'apinvs.php',
            dataType:'html',        
            success:function(data){
              $("#main").html(data); } 
          });
        }
                setInterval(callAjax,5000); 
                callAjax();
      });
```

(called the function)

It's working perfectly now.