# why use setTimeout on this slideshow?

Tags: javascript, slider

With [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/show2.shtml) article I create a simple javascript slideshow. but I can't understand why used from setTimeout on the last of codes.
setTimeout just call one times the function .

```js
<html>
<script>
var images = new Array();
images[0] = new Image().src = "1.png";
images[1] = new Image().src = "2.png";
images[2] = new Image().src = "3.png";
images[3] = new Image().src = "4.jpg";
if (!document.images){
console.log("Your Browser Does not support the images class");

}
else {console.log("welcome to your slider")}


</script>
<body>
<img src = "1.png" name = "slide" id="slider" width="300" height="100" />
</body>
<script>
var step = 0
function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
 if (!document.images)
 {
console.log("your browser doesn't support our site")}
 document.getElementById('slider').src = images[step]
 if (step<2)
  step++
 else
  step=0
  
 //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
 setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}
slideit()
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Every 2.5 seconds another slide will load?

Comment: That's the answer......

Comment: It calls it over and over since it is inside the function - it is however not excellent programming. Several issues that are not good practice. Oh and by teh way, document.images has been supported in all browsers since IE4

Comment: I know that .. I want know why used on that location

Comment: Because everything else should be done properly (loading the image), before you can go over onto the next slide.

Comment: @mplungjan the setTimeout function just run one time so we haven't other event listener . but the slideshow works fine !

Comment: No it runs again EACH time the slideit is at the end of execution

Comment: @mplungjan slideit() is out of the function and in that isn't any loop to run again

Comment: and AGAIN in `setTimeout("slideit()",2500)`

Comment: slideit() is called on document load, so it will trigger slideit(). After slideit was called, the loop will start...

Comment: Why doesn't used from setInterval on that?

Comment: because they are poor coders. Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looping as it should because the function is called again by the setTimeout at the end of the function.

```
function slideit(){
  // some code 

 //call function "slideit()" again in 2.5 seconds
 setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}
slideit(); // call it initially
```

However it is not excellent programming. Several issues that are not good practice. Oh and by the way, document.images has been supported in all browsers since IE4

I would likely code it more like this without changing your preloader:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
var step=0,images=[];
images[0] = new Image().src = "1.png";
images[1] = new Image().src = "2.png";
images[2] = new Image().src = "3.png";
images[3] = new Image().src = "4.jpg";

function slideit(){
 document.getElementById('slider').src = images[step];
 if (step>=2) step=0;
 else step++;
}
window.onload=function() {
 slideit(); // first time or wait 2.5 secs
 setInterval(slideit,2500); 
}
</script>
<body>
<img src="1.png" name="slide" id="slider" width="300" height="100" />
</body>
</html>
```

Please have a look at this too

[Execute the setInterval function without delay the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685396/execute-the-first-time-the-setinterval-without-delay)

where the function and the code

```
slideit(); // first time or wait 2.5 secs
setInterval(slideit,2500);
```

would be replaced by

```
setInterval(function slideit() {
  document.getElementById('slider').src = images[step];
  if (step>=2) step=0;
  else step++;
}(), 2500);
```