# Meteor - Refresh page every 5 min with new data set from REST API

Tags: meteor

This is what we am trying to achieve, we need to call an API every five min and refresh a page in meteor and we do not wish to use MongoDB; so the API call is directly made before the template renders and the output is displayed.

Below is the code snippet - I am calling the API every 5 min and setting it in session variable during the template rendering

```
Template.list.rendered = function(){
    Meteor.setInterval(function(){
    Meteor.call('getListFromAPI', function(error,data){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
            else{
                Session.set('availableList', data);
            }
    });
    }, 60000);
}
```

Here is the helper function which returns "availableList" to HTML for rendering -

```
Template.list.helpers({
'getList': function(){      
    return Session.get('availableList');
}
});
```

**Problem:**
It works as is meaning the page refreshes every FIVE min but the problem is when the first time the page loads, it waits for five min before the rendering.

I am fairly new to Meteor, is there any other better way I tried to move the session variable to server but session is not supported in server side.
I can understand that the reactive source "session - availableList" should be moved from rendered function but I am not sure what approach to use.

Please let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you're using `Meteor` methods this is really just a Javascript question. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6685414/191259) for how to solve it.

Basically you just need to call your method before you start your interval so it would look something like this...

```
Template.list.rendered = function(){
    Meteor.call('getListFromAPI', function(error,data){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } 
        else {
            Session.set('availableList', data);
        }
    }
    Meteor.setInterval(function(){
        Meteor.call('getListFromAPI', function(error,data){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
            else{
                Session.set('availableList', data);
            }
        });
    }, 60000);
}
```

Also just as a side note and I'm pretty sure you already know this... but `60000` ms is only 1 minute.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick reply; it worked and yes I just had 60000 ms (1 minute) for testing purpose.