# Calculating countdown by hours \ minutes instead of seconds

Tags: javascript, time, countdown

I"m trying to use this countdown but it calculates the time every second.
I want to counter to count the time by minutes or even hours, not every second because i only display days and hours.

I've tryied to remove the var seconds or minutes but the inspect elemnts showing me a purplr blink on the timer every 1 second meaning it's still calculating the time by seconds.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("April 24, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h ";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is not working right now?

Comment: the counter works fine i just need it to be calculating every 1 minute instead of 1 second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
...
}, 1000);
```

to

```
// Update the count down every 1 minute
var x = setInterval(function() {
...
}, 1000*60);
```

or

```
// Update the count down every 1 hour
var x = setInterval(function() {
...
}, 1000*60*60);
```

**Edit**

That will update your timer every minute/hour. Now, to start countdown and update every minute/hour:

```
calculateCountdown();
// Update the count down every 1 minute
var x = setInterval(function() {
  calculateDountdown();
}, 1000*60);
```

or just

```
calculateCountdown();
setInterval(calculateCountdown, 1000*60);
```

where

```
function calculateCountdown() {
  // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}
```

**Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6685414/4989081) to see how to refactor `setInterval` based solution to `setTimeout` based.**

Comment: i tried to use the minutes update and it shows nothing but after 1 minute it shows the days and hours