# Immediately invoked function expression for setTimeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to wrap a setTimeout in an immediately invoked function expression which creates the function, which then calls itself again as above, and automatically starts the loop:

Here is the reference:  [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685396/execute-the-setinterval-function-without-delay-the-first-time)

For some reason it runs once and then stopped.

```
//Spaceship move
function spaceShipMove(spaceShipToMove){

    var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random());
    spaceShipToMove.style.webkitTransform = 'translate(-3000px, ' + randomY + 'px)';
}
  //Spaceship
    var spaceShipsList = createMultipleSpaceShips(500);
    for (var i = 0; i < spaceShipsList.length; i++){
        var aSpaceShip = spaceShipsList[i];
        app.dom.mainWrapper.appendChild(aSpaceShip);


        (function t() {
            setTimeout(function (spaceShipGo) {
                spaceShipMove(spaceShipGo);
            }, i * 300, aSpaceShip)
        })();
```

Comment: [Minimal example](/help/mcve) please...

Comment: Thank you. I have amended it.

Comment: do you really need to wrap your setTimeout inside an IIFE? I mean, the setTimeout will run without it

Comment: I want this for infinite amount of time

Comment: You missed the point of using IIFE in the linked answer. Your named your function `t` but never use this name. Also, do you really need a separate timeout/interval? You almost certainly should have just one timeout scheduled at a time, and put the loop inside. That would spare you the whole problem of passing aSpaceShip there, which is not easily solvable.

Comment: If you want to call recursively your setTimeout, then you need to pass `t` in the setTimeout: just like in the linked answer. But you'll face an issue with your `i * 300` delay, I guess you'll want to delay their first occurence but keep them with the same 300ms delay.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < spaceShipsList.length; i++){
 var aSpaceShip = spaceShipsList[i];
 app.dom.mainWrapper.appendChild(aSpaceShip);

 setTimeout(spaceShipMove.bind(null, aSpaceShip), i * 300)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work.  it runs once and then stopped.

Comment: it doesn't stop, it moves the same ‘spaceShip’ over and over again