# setInterval executes functions only by the time of the interval ends

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, setinterval

I have the next **setInterval** in JS which emits the **test()** function only by the time the 5s ends:

```
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  test()
}, 5000)


function test() {
  console.log("Test") // will be emitted only in 5s
}
```

How can I tell the method to run the **test()** function without waiting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute the setInterval function without delay the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685396/execute-the-setinterval-function-without-delay-the-first-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want the function to be executed immediately, and then every 5 seconds after that. In which case, just call it initially too.

```
let interval = setInterval(() => test(), 5000)
test();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test(); //call initially and then after 5 sec
let intervalS = setInterval(() => {
  test()
}, 5000)


function test() {
  console.log("Test") // will be emitted only in 5s
}
```