# jquery click() button for me then tell me if it's done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code to press buttons for me, it will press it every second - some page just loads forever until that button appears. This code is successful:

```
(function($){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.play-button').click();
    }, 1000);

})(jQuery)
```

Now I want one step more: I want it press it only once. (still, this button only shows after a random long loading time.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute the setInterval function without delay the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685396/execute-the-setinterval-function-without-delay-the-first-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a statement to make it to run just `once`

```js
let clicked = false;

(function($) {
  setInterval(function() {
  !clicked ? $('.play-button').click() : null
  }, 1000);

})(jQuery)

$('.play-button').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked')
  clicked = !clicked
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="play-button">play button</button>
```

Comment: BTW, why there is no ";" at the end of "console.log('clicked')"?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout`:

```
(function($){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.play-button').click();
        $('.play-button').click(function(){return;});
    }, 1000);
})(jQuery)
```