# How to execute a function periodically in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I already have tried `setInterval()`, it seemed perfect but the issue is that it does not initiate the first call immediately and waits for X seconds and then it gives desired value, is there some other way or should I run it an infinite loop and put a `sleep` like functionality in it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute the setInterval function without delay the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685396/execute-the-setinterval-function-without-delay-the-first-time)

Comment: You should try cronjob https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your issue is simply it doesn't call for first time then it is OK

```js
function doThis(){
console.log("hello");
}
const time = 1000;
doThis(); // Calls for the first time
setInterval(doThis(),time); // Now it starts the samething.


//There is another option also for same thing:

setInterval(function doThis() {
  console.log('hello');
  return doThis();
}(), time);
```

But It is not recommended if `function takes longer than delayed time`
More on this statement:
https://dev.to/akanksha_9560/why-not-to-use-setinterval--2na9

https://chrisblackwell.me/setinterval-is-bad/

```js
function doThis() {
console.log("hellow");

  setTimeout(doThis, 1500);
}
doThis();
```

The problem that happens with `setInterval` doesn't happen here, because this only schedules the next iteration, not all future ones.

For `setInterval`
[image]
For `setTimeout`
[image]

Comment: If the first line in func() is the settimeout call for the next iteration, won't they be identical or close-to?