# Clearing Timeouts loop in React using useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code in Javacript (React):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timer1 = setTimeout(() => {
      // task 1
    }, 1000)

    const timer2 = setTimeout(() => {
      // task 2
    }, 2000)

    const timer3 = setTimeout(() => {
      // task 3
    }, 3000)

    // returns to the first task and starts all over again

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer1)
      clearTimeout(timer2)
      clearTimeout(timer3)
    }
  }, [])
```

my question is: how to make it so that as soon as all the timeouts are executed until the last one, I call them to be executed all over again? I simply need to run this sequence of timeouts multiple times.
I tried to throw all the setTimeouts in a function and call them in the useEffect, but I can't clear the timeouts correctly inside the hook.

Flow example:

- 1 second later: timer1 executes task 1
- +1 second later: timer2 runs task 2
- +1 second later: timer3 runs task 3
- restarts the flow from the beginning, from timer1.

Comment: Can you please include an example of the flow? to get a better understanding.

Comment: Of course, I added the flow example in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you an idea. All you need is to re-run the `useEffect` once your last timer is completed.

You can have a state which can be modified at last and pass it as dependency to the `useEffect`.

```js
const [timerCount, setTimerCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Starting new set of timers");
    const timer1 = setTimeout(() => {
        // task 1
        console.log("Task 1");
    }, 1000);

    const timer2 = setTimeout(() => {
        // task 2
        console.log("Task 2");
    }, 2000);

    const timer3 = setTimeout(() => {
        // task 3
        console.log("Task 3");

        setTimerCount((prev) => prev + 1);
    }, 3000);

    return () => {
        console.log("Killing all timers");
        clearTimeout(timer1);
        clearTimeout(timer2);
        clearTimeout(timer3);
    };
}, [timerCount]);
```

Comment: your idea is very good, it worked for me. I'll keep looking at the other answers from here to see more possibilities. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval() method to create a sort of loop. It would look like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
  
        //Implementing the setInterval method. I put a delay of 8 seconds to 
        //make sure all your tasks run to completion, but you can play with 
        //it
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            const timer1 = setTimeout(() => {
              // task 1
            }, 1000)

            const timer2 = setTimeout(() => {
              // task 2
            }, 2000)

            const timer3 = setTimeout(() => {
              // task 3
            }, 3000)

            
        }, 8000);
  
        //Clearing the interval
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
            
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: the problem is that when trying to clear the variables do not exist in the scope

Comment: The change I made should fix it.

Comment: Keep in mind there's actually no need to use clearTimeout unless you want to cancel the timer before it runs out for a reason or another.

Comment: Your idea worked for me, I did several tests to see if it really was what I needed and it worked, thank you very much for the solution!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help.

Comment: the only drawback of your solution is that the setinterval only starts running after the last delay, I will need to do it in another way.

Comment: what do you mean by after the last delay

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6685414/19925202 this should fix your issue

Comment: @Lucas016 ^^^ check that

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the interval duration once the 3rd timeout completes it's cycle.

For ex:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const intervalDuration = 3000;     
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // task 1 logic here
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // task 2
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // task 3
    }, 3000);
  }, intervalDuration);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: the first problem I see with setInterval, is that it starts only after the delay occurs, and the second problem is that all setTimeouts inside it need to be "unmounted" using clearTimeout