# How to use the Tincr Google Chrome extension for live reloading local files

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have tried using the Tincr Chrome Extension now on Windows and Linux (Ubuntu) and it still does not seem to do the Live Reloading it claims to [on its website](http://tin.cr/) when I am editing the file in an external editor. The Tin.cr website claims:

> Any CSS or JavaScript changes you make in any editor reloads in Chrome
>   without refreshing the whole page

To explain further, I have tried installing this extension as an unpacked extension in Chrome with Developer Mode checked under `chrome://chrome/extensions/` as suggested in the [Tincr documentation](http://tin.cr/docs.html). I have also tried installing this extension directly through the Chrome Web Store. The effect has been the same.

In terms of setting up Tincr, I have tried opening up my file locally without a web server using `file://C:/htdocs/file.html` which Tincr claims in its documentation it can read automatically without needing any setup, and also I have tried opening up my file via an Apache Web Server on localhost e.g. `localhost/file.html` and setting up the Project Type in Tincr as `Http Web Server` as suggested in the documentation, but both ways have been to no avail.

In terms of editing my local file, I have used a number of different external editors, for example, Geany on Ubuntu and Titanium Studio on Windows.

After editing the file in the editor I have left the page I am editing open in my Chrome browser with the Tincr plugin setup and enabled. However, after saving my file in the editor and looking to see if it live reloads in Chrome, nothing happens. The file simply stays the same. Again, to reiterate, this is happening in both Windows and Linux (Ubuntu).

And so my question is this: has anyone successful tried using this extension with an external editor and if so could you please detail the steps to get live reload to work as I'm beginning to think this may be a bug in the extension?

Comment: I second the problem above, can't seem to get it to work even with file:// ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I may have an explaination. Having a look at the google groups for Tincr, it appears **Tincr does not support html file refresh**, and that it **can only detect changes in either css or javascript**.

source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tincr-for-chrome-devtools/VyC0mavLs_A

Comment: Yes - it looks pretty likely that this is the reason and why on the website they specifically mention javascript and css but **not** html

Comment: If you're looking for an alternative to Tincr, [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) is a good one, not free (as in free beer) but it works :)

Comment: I would use this, however LiveReload (or guard-livereload in my case) uses `RubyGems` and I just hate `RubyGems`!

Comment: It seems that it still doesn't... 2014 June.

Comment: I wonder, WHY it cannot detect html change, any reason for that?