# auto reload local html file with Live.js when change has occurred on the files

Tags: reload

live.js sending consecutive HEAD requests to the server and if there is a change in the html, css or js file, live.js refreshing the data.

It's very simple Just link the file to the html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="live.js">
```

It works well if the files on a server but if I'm working on a local computer with notepad It does not work.

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

In general, `live.js` does not support the file protocol. However, there is a very easy work-around (suggested by @MarcelValdezOrozco in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29466420/1804173)):

If you have Python installed, you can start a local webserver simply by running

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Run it in the same directory as your HTML file. By default, the server will list the content of the directory. Navigate to your HTML. Now auto-reloading using `live.js` should work.

Comment: in python3 use `python3 -m http.server <port optionally>`