# live.js vs. python SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, real-time, simplehttpserver

**The idea**

To speed up my development I want to [automatically refresh the browser if I change the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29466420/7082264) `test.html`.

**My setup**

I'm on Linux and I start my server with

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

in a terminal so that I can open my `test.html` in my browser with

```
http://localhost:8000/test.html
```

I have to open the `test.html` like this (and not with `file://`) because I use [live.js](http://livejs.com/). This javascript tool checks every second (!) if `test.html` has changed..and if so it refreshes the browser automatically.

**My problem**

The checking interval keeps increasing...

[image]

...and increasing....

[image]

...and never seems to stop

[image]

At the end if I change the `test.html` file is takes a lot of time to refresh the browser.

**My question**

I want to work live.js in real time but I think the server slows the process down. Am I right?

*How can I get live.js to work in real time?*

**EDIT**

As Serge Ballesta suggested I increased the interval to 10 sec but this doesn't work neither.

[image]

Comment: What would be the reason to check for a file update every second?

Comment: It's on a development environment. I want to see my changes in real time.

Comment: To make sure, I would either install an Apache httpd server and test the unchanged Live.js against it, or try to tweak Live.js to use an interval of 10s. If either works at a constant rate, then it would be an evidence that `SimpleHTTPServer` is not meant to absord a charge of 1 request per second.