# How to Enable Hot Reloading with Bun in a React Application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime, bun

I've been developing a React application and decided to use Bun as my JavaScript runtime for its great performance claims. However, I seem to have stumbled upon an issue regarding hot reloading of my React application.

I start my application using the command bun --watch run dev.tsx and it runs fine initially. However, when I make changes to my App.js file (or any other file), the changes are not being reflected live in the browser. Even after saving the file, I have to manually restart the server to see the changes. I was expecting that the --watch flag would enable some sort of hot reloading, but it appears not to.

Here's what I run in my terminal:

> ```
> Listening on http://localhost:3000
> GET /
> GET /index.css
> GET /index.js
> GET /bunlogo.svg
> GET /favicon.ico
> GET /manifest.json
> GET /logo192.png
> ```

I was wondering if Bun has built-in support for hot module replacement (HMR) or if there's any workaround to enable live reloading in the browser when I make changes to my files.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Bun v 0.x had a `bun dev` command which had functionality to hot-reload react, but it was removed in 1.0.

HMR is discussed in [Issue 833](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/833).

Bun's --hot option is NOT for hot-reloading on the browser as @samnoon said in his answer, but there are a few ways we can get hot reloading in the browser anyways:

1. Use a framework like [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) to hot reload. (Recommended in bun's docs)
2. Use one of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588658/auto-reload-browser-when-i-save-changes-to-html-file-in-chrome), such as

   - using [Live.js](http://livejs.com/) script
   - [reload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload) npm package
   - [refresh the page every 3 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31141584/5936629)
   - [live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) vscode extension
3. Use websockets to trigger a window reload on detected file change, like in [this comment](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/833#issuecomment-1594136474)

Answer (score 0):

With Bun you can use **Watch mode:**

`--watch`, which hard restarts Bun's process when imported files change.

Use:

```
bun --watch dev.tsx
```

Link to official docs: https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/hot#hot-mode

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with either `--hot` mode or `--watch` mode in bun.

`--watch` mode will hard restart Bun's process when imported files change.

`--hot` mode will soft reload the code (without restarting the process) when imported files change.

Preferably, you can use bun `--hot` to enable hot reloading when executing code with Bun. This is distinct from `--watch` mode in that Bun does not hard-restart the entire process. Instead, it detects code changes and updates its internal module cache with the new code.

#### To use `--hot` mode:

```
bun --hot dev.tsx
```

**Note:** [According to official documentation](https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/hot#hot-mode), This is not the same as hot reloading in the browser. Many frameworks provide a "hot reloading" experience, where you can edit & save your frontend code (say, a React component) and see the changes reflected in the browser without refreshing the page. Bun's `--hot` is the server-side equivalent of this experience.

**Reference:**

[0] https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/hot

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to enable browser hot module reload in Bun via websockets.

I add the prefix "browser" because Bun already has a feature called hot module reload but is is more a "server" hot module reload as pointed to other answers.

In order to enable it you need to start a websocket server directly in the `Bun.serve()` call:

```js
Bun.serve({
  fetch(req, ser) {
    if(ser.upgrade(req)) return;

    // return a `Response` with your component 
    ...
  },
  websocket: {
    message() {},
    open() {},
    close() {},
    drain() {},
  },
})
```

In the server that's it, we now need to tell the browser to reload when the socket server is closed, in order for this you can add the following script inside a `<script>` tag:

```js
(() => {
  const socketUrl = "ws://localhost:3000";
  let socket = new WebSocket(socketUrl);
  console.log(socket);
  socket.addEventListener("close", () => {
    const interAttemptTimeoutMilliseconds = 100;
    const maxDisconnectedTimeMilliseconds = 3000;
    const maxAttempts = Math.round(
      maxDisconnectedTimeMilliseconds / interAttemptTimeoutMilliseconds,
    );
    let attempts = 0;
    const reloadIfCanConnect = () => {
      attempts++;
      if (attempts > maxAttempts) {
        console.error("Could not reconnect to dev server.");
        return;
      }
      socket = new WebSocket(socketUrl);
      socket.addEventListener("error", () => {
        setTimeout(reloadIfCanConnect, interAttemptTimeoutMilliseconds);
      });
      socket.addEventListener("open", () => {
        location.reload();
      });
    };
    reloadIfCanConnect();
  });
})();
```

You can find an explanation of this script [here](https://www.bscotch.net/post/create-a-live-reload-server).

Now run your file with `bun --watch run index.`, please use `--watch` and not `--hot` because we need to close the web server socket at every change.

Now make an edit of your files, you should see your browser automatically reload.