# How to write a batch file that will cause firefox to refresh each time a file is saved in my IDE?

Tags: firefox, shell, ide, batch-file, refresh

I am a web developer who uses netbeans IDE. I would like firefox to refresh each time I save a file in netbeans so I can see the updated changes without having to manually refresh.

I searched and there doesn't seem to be any such features built in to netbeans and third part addons avaliable for this task are either depreciated or not avaliable on windows.

Can someone please think of a way to write a batch file that can do this? So when I press CNTRL + S while netbeans in open, then firefox (if open) will refresh. I know nothing about batch files or shell scripting in general so I'm at a loss here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Batch-file is not your solution in this case. Change batch-file to vbscript. Firefox does not have a command line argument to refresh the page, and batch-files do not have the ability to emulate keystrokes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346716/firefox-auto-refresh-on-file-change

Answer (score 1):

have you tried http://livejs.com?