# Countdown auto-refresh; when there is no interactivity

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, flash, browser, refresh

I built a web app using AS3/Flash. The application is being featured on a touch screen monitor as kiosk therefore no keyboard or mouse. At the moment I just used the simple meta refresh to refresh the page every 10 mins.

Issue: when users are interacting with the application, the 10 mins counts down is running in the background consistently and the page refresh automatically while they are still interacting with the content.

I need application, browser extention or jquery snippet that monitors if theres any interactivity, and refreshes after the user stops interacting. So if the user stops, the countdown for 10 mins starts. If next user starts using it, the countdown restarts.

This is similar discussion i came across but its on file-change.
[How do I make Firefox auto-refresh on file change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346716/firefox-auto-refresh-on-file-change)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into some sort of kiosk mode extension instead. The problem with refreshing the page using script is that if the connection is down, the browser would end up struck on the 404 page. As there is no keyboard, no one could push F5 to refresh it.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct and I did consider it. Some kiosk are hosted locally where these is poor connection (wi-fi). But it would be ideal to setup a  browser extension. if you know of any let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps... use a timer to check for interaction on stage, and point a URLLoader to a test file on your webservice domain to check if everything is up and running. If so, refresh calling a `location.reload` on javascript.

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class TimeoutRefresh {

        private var tt:Timer;
        private var online:Boolean;
        private var ldr:URLLoader;

        public function TimeoutRefresh(stageRef:Stage, minutes:int) {
            //set up timer
            tt = new Timer(minutes * 60 * 1000);
            tt.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, checkConnection);
            tt.start();
            //listen for interaction
            stageRef.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, refreshTimer);
            stageRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, refreshTimer);
        }

        private function refreshTimer(e:MouseEvent):void {
            //some interaction on stage, restart timer
            tt.reset();
            tt.start();
        }

        private function checkConnection(e:TimerEvent):void {
            //no interaction, stop the timer
            tt.stop();
            //check for internet connection
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("www.yourWebserviceDomain.com/aTestFile.txt");
            ldr = new URLLoader(req);
            ldr.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIoErrorEvent);
            ldr.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoaderActivity);
            ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderActivity);
        }

        private function onIoErrorEvent(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
            //The remote server is not working, maybe it fixes itself in a while...
            tt.reset();
            tt.start();
            //remove listeners
            checkConnectionDone();
        }

        private function onLoaderActivity(e:ProgressEvent):void {
            //The webservice is up and running, lets refresh...
            if (ExternalInterface.available) ExternalInterface.call("document.location.reload");
            //and reset timer
            tt.reset();
            tt.start();
            //remove listeners
            checkConnectionDone();
        }

        private function checkConnectionDone():void {
            if (ldr.bytesLoaded < ldr.bytesTotal) ldr.close();
            ldr.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIoErrorEvent);
            ldr.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoaderActivity);
            ldr.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderActivity);
            ldr = null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Im receiving the follow error: 
Line 71 1120: Access of undefined property onProgress.

Comment: Sorry @user1328229, now its fixed. The idea is to cancel the load when the the first progress event is triggered, theres no need to go for the full file, you just need to know you can reach it.