# Automatic refresh the page when changes while running pub serve (dart)

Tags: dart

I'm using pub serve to run my page. I noticed that there are tools like `lite-server` for npm, that make sure that after file contents are changed, the web page is automatically refreshed.

Anyone got something like that working for dart using pub serve? I thought maybe some grinder script with the [watcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/watcher) package could make that work?

Answer (score 1):

Pub should handle monitoring and autodeployment of changes itself when run in debug or release mode.

You can verify this works correctly by issuing from your project root

```
pub serve
```

then make a change to a html or dart file and verify that the project is automatically rebuilt.

If this is not working, you might try experimenting with the `--force-poll` option when running pub serve.  Per documentation:

```
--[no-]force-poll    Force the use of a polling filesystem watcher.
```

Comment: This doesn't update the browser. `pub serve` would need integration with autoreload.

Comment: Yes, it does rebuild, but I basically, want that the browser refreshes automatically after rebuilding.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.  What browser/client are you using?  If Dartium/Chrome, see this question, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512014/automatically-refresh-page-when-dart-source-files-change